# Adding Button in Gmail for web users

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am trying to figure out how can I add a button to the Gmail compose window.
Please see the image below for better idea..

[image]

Using Google App Script I have achieved some functionality where we can create almost anything, but How can We create a button in Gmail?

Even if not compose window as shown in image above, I will like to learn how to add button at any place in Gmail.com's window using gadget or any other way.

Note: I have tried many things and ended up nowhere, The Sidebar is deprecated by google so please don't highlight that..

I will be glad if any working code to add button in Gmail available,

Thanks in advance

Comment: would chrome extensions work for you?

Comment: Thank you for you replay Adelin, this is Not something I am looking for as that will become browser specific! I need generic solution.. that might work with some hosted app on gmail or some widget, like depricated sidebars use to work.

Comment: You can add email parsers that will work on the content of email already received. but adding functionality to the editor itself will require a browser plugin as @Adelin points out.

Comment: @ Jonathon thank you for your reply, I know using browser plugin(Chrome) we can achieve that easily, but that is again dependency that we need to carry through out the project life.. !!

Comment: @MarmiK and can you tell me how to add custom button in gmail using chrome extension give me reference for that